# How to solve MySQL error which occurs while loading image

Tags: mysql

When I am opening a local connection in MySQL, an error occurring while loading image search_sidebar.png.How can I solve this problem in MySQL? I have attached a screenshot of error showing[image]
I am using MySQL Server 5.7 and MySQL Workbench 6.3 version 6.3.8

Comment: Please provide more detail or query, now it is totally unclear what you are asking?

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot ?

Comment: Now please give the answer

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve the problem. Also, is this related to programming after all?

Answer (score 39):

To repair without completely re-installing MySQL:

ON Windows 10

- Go to Control Panel
- Uninstall a Program
- Find MySQL (In My Case MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE)
- Right Click and select "Repair"

[image: Control Panel Repair Option for MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE]

Once installation is complete, please restart MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE

Hopefully this resolves the issue for you.

Answer (score 6):

Fixed by reinstalling and choosing *Repair* option.

**Background**

Previously, i upgraded MySQL Workbench from earlier edition to latest version 6.3.10. It worked fine for many days but one fine day after Windows restart it started showing *Error while loading image* popup. I tried several times closing and starting MySQL Workbench but same popup appears each time.

**Solution**

I downloaded fresh copy of MySQL Workbench from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=474210 and chose *Repair* option during installation. My databases and everything else is intact and working as before. Additionally, it resolved popup issue.

**Note**

There is no need to remove MySQL Workbench, just choosing *Repair* option during install worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed Workbench from MySql Installer and Reinstall version 6.3.7

Now working...